How to send option to package from class option OR order of option processing with \PassOptionsToPackage?
I’m developing a combination of classes and packages, where the package is used to define a color set (that should be usable in different classes) and has an option color-mode=cmyk|rgb|gray to device wether it should be CMYK, RGB or Gray. The class has an option target-media=print|online that affects the layout but also should set the correct color mode. However I want to be able to override this decision.
So if I say
\documentclass{myclass}

the target should be online and thus the model should be rgb. When it is
\documentclass[target-media=print]{myclass}

the target ist print and the model should change to cmyk. However I still want to be able to say
\documentclass[target-media=print,color-model=gray]{myclass}

and this is not working.
So in the following MWE the output should be
Target: print
Media: gray

but it is
Target: print
Media: cmyk

I use \PassOptionsToPackage in the target-media option and it works but it seems to be a problem (or I misuse/misunderstood something) with the order of option processing. It seems like the class options are given to the package first and then the ons form \PassOptionsToPackage are processed.
\begin{filecontents}[force]{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypackage}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\tl_new:N \g_pkg_value_tl
\DeclareKeys {
  color-mode .code:n = {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_pkg_value_tl { #1 }
  },
  color-mode .initial:n = { rgb(ini) },
}
\ProcessKeyOptions
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypackagevalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_pkg_value_tl}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}
\tl_new:N \g_cls_value_tl
\keys_define:nn { myclass } {
  target-media .code:n = {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_cls_value_tl { #1 }
    \PassOptionsToPackage{color-mode=cmyk}{mypackage}
  },
  target-media .initial:n = { online(ini) },
}
\ProcessKeyOptions [ myclass ]
\NewDocumentCommand{\myclassvalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_cls_value_tl}
\RequirePackage{mypackage}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
  target-media=print,
  color-mode=gray,
]{myclass}

\begin{document}
Target: \myclassvalue

Model: \mypackagevalue
\end{document}

So what is the prober way of implementing the desired behavior or in other words how can I pass an option to the package while still maintaining the order of options given in \documentclass?

Bonus question: Is it still recommended to use \keys_define:nn or should I switch to \DeclareKeys?

Add an option color-mode to the class, so it is also passed to the package.

Yea, I thought about that too but it seems redundant to have the same option twice …

Not if you want both the class and the package to handle the option. Alternatively, you could pass all or all unknown options to the package, but that likely has side-effects you may not want.

@cfr  you referring to which point? How about \keys_define:nn vs \DeclareKeys?

@yannisl Sorry. I meant the comment about redundancy. I'm not sure about the keys. I thought \DeclareKeys was mostly intended for use in non-exp3 code. I tend to use \keys_define:nn because it is more flexible.

@cfr Thanks, I also moved any new code I write to keys_define:nn I was just curious to get your thoughts on it.

Do you really want to pass every option to the base class rather than just the unrecognised ones?

@all: Thanks for your ideas! Then I’ll stick to \keys_define:nn.

@cfr: Do you think I should not pass all options? And am I right that you would suggest using \PassOptionsToClass with the unknown ones instead of \LoadClassWithOptions. Are there any drawbacks with the latter one I don’t see?

ad redundancy: I don’t want the class to handle the option. I just want the class to pass it to the package correctly. So in my eyes it's not a functionality of the class thus it seems strange to have this as a class option. But it seems like this is the only way to go …?
@cabohah you might post this as an answer.

Well, it depends what they are, but usually for the options I'm defining, I want to control what is done with them. That might include passing them to the other class. Or it might not. Usually, I'd pass some and not others. But the unknown ones I'd always pass on because maybe the other class knows what to make of them.

@cfr: Thanks I’ll think about that.

\keys_define:nn is the same as \DeclareKeys, under the hood \DeclareKeys just calls that after setting a sensible default for the module name if you omitted the optional argument. If your package uses expl3 code anyway I'd advice using \keys_define:nn (for minuscule performance reasons).

@Skillmon so you could use e.g. .tl_set:N in \DeclareKeys? that was not obvious to me from the documentation. (I can guess the reasons for this, though.)

@cfr correct, you could do that. You can use any ltkeys names inside \keys_define:nn and any l3keys names inside \DeclareKeys if you so wish. See the documentation on page 16, section 4.4 in clsguide.pdf which reads: "The full range of properties, provided by l3keys, can also be used for more powerful processing. See interface3 for the full details."

@cfr and while you can use the ltkeys names inside \keys_define:nn note that this direction doesn't make too much sense, since it doesn't offer any more functionality, after all the ltkeys names of properties are just aliases of existing l3keys properties.

@Skillmon Thanks. I find it hard to keep track of where expl3/l3/l2e/lt things are documented ....

@cfr same, for some things I just know where to look, for others I'm puzzled myself.

The problem here is, that you already explicitly pass option color-mode to the package depending on other class options. Passing options explicitly to a package is always handled after handling of global options in packages. This is to be able to overwrite options from \documentclass when loading a package.
So to handle the global package option after the option that is explicitly passed by a class option, the class must also pass the global package option explicitly to the package:
\begin{filecontents}[force]{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypackage}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\tl_new:N \g_pkg_value_tl
\DeclareKeys {
  color-mode .code:n = {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_pkg_value_tl { #1 }
  },
  color-mode .initial:n = { rgb(ini) },
}
\ProcessKeyOptions
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypackagevalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_pkg_value_tl}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}
\tl_new:N \g_cls_value_tl
\keys_define:nn { myclass } {
  target-media .code:n = {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_cls_value_tl { #1 }
    \PassOptionsToPackage{color-mode=cmyk}{mypackage}
  },
  target-media .initial:n = { online(ini) },
  color-mode .code:n = {
    \PassOptionsToPackage{ \CurrentOption } { mypackage }
  }
}
\ProcessKeyOptions [ myclass ]
\NewDocumentCommand{\myclassvalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_cls_value_tl}
\RequirePackage{mypackage}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
  target-media=print,
  color-mode=gray,
]{myclass}

\begin{document}
Target: \myclassvalue

Model: \mypackagevalue
\end{document}

Another solution would be, if the package would also  interpret the class option instead of passing it from within the class:
\begin{filecontents}[force]{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypackage}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\tl_new:N \g_pkg_value_tl
\DeclareKeys {
  color-mode .code:n = {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_pkg_value_tl { #1 }
  },
  color-mode .initial:n = { rgb(ini) },
  target-media .meta:n = { color-mode=cmyk }
}
\ProcessKeyOptions
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypackagevalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_pkg_value_tl}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}
\tl_new:N \g_cls_value_tl
\keys_define:nn { myclass } {
  target-media .code:n = {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_cls_value_tl { #1 }
  },
  target-media .initial:n = { online(ini) },
}
\ProcessKeyOptions [ myclass ]
\NewDocumentCommand{\myclassvalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_cls_value_tl}
\RequirePackage{mypackage}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
  target-media=print,
  color-mode=gray,
]{myclass}

\begin{document}
Target: \myclassvalue

Model: \mypackagevalue
\end{document}

It's hard so say, which one is the better solution, if you are the author of both, the class and the package. If you are the class author only, you should use the first. If you are the package author only, you should use the second.

Thanks for this solution/explanation. Yes I author both and must think about wich way to go.

Another possibility is for both files to share the same key path. In the following I renamed your module to tobi and added a submodule part to the name (cls and pkg), so the names of your variables would include either tobi_cls or tobi_pkg.
As a result we only need to parse the class options separately if the package was loaded before the class was, as otherwise the options stemming from the class wouldn't yet be defined and correctly parsed, hence we keep track of that.
In the following the class code was altered relatively much, and I left some comments explaining some reasoning behind the changes, the package code is only altered in a minimal way.
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{\@currname}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\tl_new:N \g_tobi_pkg_value_tl
\keys_define:nn { tobi }
  {
    color-mode .code:n = {
      \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tobi_pkg_value_tl \l_keys_value_tl
    },
    color-mode .initial:n = { rgb(ini) },
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions [ tobi ]
\NewDocumentCommand \mypackagevalue {} { \tl_use:N \g_tobi_pkg_value_tl }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{\@currname}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}

\bool_new:N \l_tobi_cls_pkg_loaded_earlier_bool
\@ifpackageloaded{\@currname}
  { \bool_set_true:N \l_tobi_cls_pkg_loaded_earlier_bool }
  {}

\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}
\tl_new:N \g_tobi_cls_value_tl
\keys_define:nn { tobi } {
  % if target-media should only be a choice out of two possible values, it'd
  % make much more sense to define it in the following way:
  target-media .choices:nn = { online, print } {
    \tl_gset_eq:NN \g_tobi_cls_value_tl \l_keys_choice_tl
    % the key is guaranteed to exist when the option parsing is actually done
    \tl_if_eq:NnTF \g_tobi_cls_value_tl { online }
      { \keys_set:nn { tobi } { color-mode = cmyk } }
      { \keys_set:nn { tobi } { color-mode = rgb } }
  },
  % you don't want to set the initial value here, instead define the
  % `target-media` directly, or else your initial state will be <online(ini)>
  % and <cmyk> instead of <online(ini)> and <rbg(ini)>.
  %target-media .initial:n = { online(ini) },
}
% better set the initial value like this
\tl_set:Nn \g_tobi_cls_value_tl { online(ini) }

% load the package here, it'll add further options to the `tobi` key group
\RequirePackage{\@currname}

% only parse the options if the package was loaded before the class was, in
% which case the additional keys from the class wouldn't get correctly parsed),
% otherwise it's rather unlikely that we need the Future-options mechanism for a
% class (which would be the only other reason to include the
% `\ProcessKeyOptions` here, that could only really happen if the class somehow
% end up being loaded multiple times using `\LoadClass` or
% `\LoadClassWithOptions`).
\bool_if:NT \l_tobi_cls_pkg_loaded_earlier_bool { \ProcessKeyOptions [ tobi ] }

\NewDocumentCommand \myclassvalue {} { \tl_use:N \g_tobi_cls_value_tl }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
  target-media=print,
  color-mode=gray,
]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Target: \myclassvalue

Model: \mypackagevalue
\end{document}


interesting. so target media isn't a class/package option?

@cfr well, it is (and isn't). With this setup it just doesn't make a big difference whether the options are parsed as part of the package or as part of the class. That distinction gets rather blurry, they are just treated as the same module. One could separate them out again, by employing submodules or key groups, and while processing the options one could define an unknown handler which selectively forwards to either submodule and use the same supermodule. But I guess that's rather over the top and not needed in reality (or I hope?).

where does target media get processed? isn't it being defined after the processing is done?

@cfr no, the first point the option might get processed is during the \RequirePackage call, which comes after the definition.

oh, sorry. I was reading them the wrong way round. (pkg vs. cls, I mean)

If you decide to use another package for option processing you can actually decide which options are parsed first and which later.
The following uses expkv-opt for this (as it's my package), but other solutions are available as well.
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.sty}
\ProvidesExplPackage{\@currname}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
\tl_new:N \g_pkg_value_tl
\ekvdefinekeys{mypackage}
  {
    % gstore is (currently) compatible with \tl_gset:Nn (and most likely stay
    % that way, unless the kernel team decides to change the underlying data
    % structure of a tl, which is unlikely)
     gstore~  color-mode = \g_pkg_value_tl
    ,initial~ color-mode = rgb(ini)
  }
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{mypackage}
\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{mypackage}
\ekvoProcessFutureOptions{mypackage}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypackagevalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_pkg_value_tl}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{\@currname}{2024/07/23}{1}{demo}
\LoadClassWithOptions{scrbook}
\tl_new:N \g_cls_value_tl
\keys_define:nn { myclass } {
  target-media .code:n = {
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_cls_value_tl { #1 }
    \PassOptionsToPackage{color-mode=cmyk}{\@currname}
  },
  target-media .initial:n = { online(ini) },
}
\ProcessKeyOptions [ myclass ]
\NewDocumentCommand{\myclassvalue}{}{\tl_use:N \g_cls_value_tl}
\RequirePackage{\@currname}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
  target-media=print,
  color-mode=gray,
]{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Target: \myclassvalue

Model: \mypackagevalue
\end{document}

